# Как написать этот код чтобы работало, но не расписывать каждый полученный параметр (a, b, c, d, e)

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, аргументы

```
def command(a, b, c, d, e, ...):
    for i in range(a, b, c, d, e, ...):
        print(i, 'Этим способом вылазиет ошибка')

command(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...)
```

Comment: `def command(*args): for i in [*args]: ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`*args`** — это сокращение от «arguments» (аргументы)

**`*args`** - конструкция  используется для распаковки аргументов соответствующего типа,
позволяя вызывать функции со списком аргументов переменной длины.

Благодаря использованию **`*`** мы создали список позиционных аргументов на основе того, что было передано функции при вызове.

Оператор **`*`** можно использовать не только в объявлениях функций, но и при их вызове.

```
def command(*args): 
    print(args)
    for i in args:
        print(i, 'Hello')

command(1, 2, 3, 4, 5 )
```